# call javascript function from haml link_to

Tags: javascript, onclick, haml, link-to

I would like to invoke a javascript function (without JQuery) when the onclick even fires from a link_to tag in haml. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
link_to "your link", href, :onclick => "jsFunction"
```

Or, doing everything JS side:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a')
    {
        return e;//not clicked on link
    }
    //a link was clicked, maybe check class or id or other stuff to narrow it down
    //if a link you were interested in was clicked:
    return theClickFunction.apply(target,[e]);
},false);
```

Comment: I can't call coffeescript function with this link. It works only when I add () to function

Answer (score 21):

Here’s how to do it using Rails link_to in haml:

```
= link_to "my link", "", :onclick => "my_function(); return false"
```

Comment: This answer was more helpful.

Comment: @YuraVasylenko the (); executes the function. my_function without is "Hey, i'm a function"... with (); "Hey i'm a function execute me". You could pass my_function as a parameter (pass the whole function) if you pass my_function(); you pass the result of executing the function

Answer (score 9):

The pure HAML equivalent to @edouardbriere's answer:

```
%a{href: '#', onclick: 'my_function(); return false;'} my link
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<a onclick="YOURMETHOD;"/>A link</a>
```

if you would also like to prevent the location change add `return false` after your method call.

Comment: The original question was regarding HAML links; not HTML, in this case.